# Is it possible to increment the modulo operator in later loop iterations?

Tags: c, modulo

I am trying to construct a simple program which adds together the digits of a long number. I attempted to do this by using a loop employing the modulo operator and some basic arithmetic. I want to increment the modulo operator by multiplying it by ten on each iteration of the loop in order to reach the next digit. I want to check if my code is correct, however, I receive errors pertaining to the lines involving the modulo operations and I'm not quite sure why.

This was my attempted construction:

```
{
    long i = 0;
    long b;
    int m = 1;
    do
    {
        long number = get_long("Number?\n");
        long a = number % m;
        b = number - a;
        long c = b % m x 10;
        long d = c / m;
        {
            i = i + d;
        }
        {
            m = m x 10
        }
    }
    while (b > 0);
    printf("%ld\n", i);
}
```

Edit:

I made the basic error of writing "x" instead of "*". However, having fixed this, I no longer receive errors, but the program simply returns "0". Any diagnosis would be appreciated.

```
int main(void)
{
    long i = 0;
    long b;
    int m = 10;
    long number = get_long("Number?\n");
    do
    {
        long a = number % m;
        b = number - a;
        long c = b % m * 10;
        long d = c / m;
        {
            i = i + d;
        }
        {
            m = m * 10;
        }
    }
    while (b > 0);
    printf("%ld\n", i);
}
```

Comment: What is m = m x 10?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That was supposed to increment m by x10 on each iteration. Have I done this incorrectly?

Comment: @BlueKhakis If you mean the multiply operation you need to write at least m = m * 10;

Comment: Just read the number as a string and save the hassle of calculating digits (apart of shifting them by `'0'`).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ah yes, that's a very basic mistake, sorry, I'm quite inexperienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your revised code:

```c
long c = b % m * 10;
```

this line will evaluate `(b % m)` and then multiply it by 10 because of the order of operations.
I presume what you actually want is:

```c
long c = b % (m * 10);
```

Secondly, the following line determines which digit you start at:

```c
int m = 10;
```

and this line determines how many digits between the ones you include in your total:

```c
m = m * 10;
```

So for this configuration, it will start at the 2nd digit from the right and add every digit.
So for the number `1234`, you'd get `3 + 2 + 1 = 6`.

If you want to add every digit, you could set:

```c
int m = 10;
```

and you'd get `4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10`.

Alternatively, if you had used:

```c
m = m * 10;
```

you'd have `3 + 1 = 4`.

Comment: The program runs perfectly now! Thank you, Mr Avocado, for your kindness and patience.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're likely getting errors due to these lines:

```c
long c = b % m x 10;
```

```c
m = m x 10
```

This is because `x` is not a valid operator.
The multiplication operator is `*`:

```c
long c = b % m * 10;
```

```c
m = m * 10;
```

As for your approach, I would suggest, instead of changing the modulo operand, you simply divide the original number by 10 to shift it one digit each operation.

For example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sumofdigits = 0;
    int num = 12345;
    
    while(num > 0) {
        sumofdigits += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    
    printf("%d", sumofdigits);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect. I've modified my code and no longer receive any error messages. But for some reason, when I run it and try to input a number, it keeps reasking me for a number. Why might this be?

Comment: @BlueKhakis, in your `do...while` loop, you include `get_long("Number?\n");`, the function that asks for a number. If you only want this to be called once, you should call this before `do`.

Comment: Thanks, now it accepts the number but simply returns 0. I'm still trying to use my original formulation, because the next thing I'll need to do is to construct a formula which adds every OTHER number. I'm pretty sure my maths is correct- so is something in my syntax gone awry?

Comment: @BlueKhakis, it's certainly possible using your original method, though I'd still recommend simply dividing the number by 100 if your goal was to add every other number. As for your syntax, it might be helpful to post a separate question with the updated code.

Comment: I had hoped to- but apparently one can only post once every 90 minutes.

Comment: @BlueKhakis, in that case, could you append your new code to your original question as an edit?

Comment: @BlueKhakis thanks, I've posted another answer regarding the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The reduced-sum of the digits of a number is the same as that number modulo 9.

### Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int number = 57283;
    
    printf("%d \n", number%9);
    // 5 + 7 + 2 + 8 + 3 == 25 ==> 2 + 5 == 7
    // 57283 % 9 == 7
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use loops to get the reduced sum:

```
int sum_of_digits(int num)
{
    int sum;
    do
    {
        sum = 0;
        while(num)
        {
            sum += num%10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        num = sum;
    } while (sum >9);
    return sum;
}
```

But if you only want the simple sum of digits (one pass only):

```
int sum_of_digits(int num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(num)
    {
        sum += num%10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the sum of the digits of a variable of type long by the two operators modulo (%) and division (/), you start with the operator modulo to find the remainder of the division (the digits) then, you add this degit to the sum, then you do the division / 10 to overwrite (the summed digit) until the number is equal to 0 like this:

```
int main()
{
     long number=0,m=0;
     printf("Give a number :");
     scanf("%ld",&number);
     long s=0,temp=number;
     while(number != 0)
     {
        m=number%10;
        s+=m;
        number/=10;
     }
     printf("\n%The sum of the digits of the Number %ld is : %ld\n",temp,s);
}
```